# ListView with InputTransparent property set to True is affecting the button inside the ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I wanted my ListView to be not scrollable and clickable so I set the property InputTransparent = true, however, I also have buttons inside the ListView so I am not able to click the button as well.
I tried setting the InputTransparent property of my button to false but it didn't work.

Any advice or do you know any workaround so I can just display my list that is not clickable and not scrollable?

Here is my XAML

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionList}"
                                  SeparatorVisibility="None" 
                                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                  InputTransparent="True">

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="24" 
                                                         WidthRequest="24" 
                                                         Margin="0,0,16,0"
                                                         InputTransparent="True">
                                                <Frame CornerRadius="20" 
                                                       HasShadow="False" 
                                                       Padding="0" Margin="0" 
                                                       BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                                       HeightRequest="24" 
                                                       WidthRequest="24">
                                                    <Label
                                                       FontSize="16" 
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                       Text="a" 
                                                       TextColor="White"/>
                                                </Frame>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout Margin="16,0,68,0" WidthRequest="324" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Question}" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,30.5,0" HeightRequest="30.5">
                                                <StackLayout Margin="0,0,12,0">
                                                    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="YES" Command="{Binding }" WidthRequest="219" FontSize="12">

                                                    </Button>
                                                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1.52" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,-8,0,0"

                                                    </BoxView>
                                                </StackLayout>

                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="NO" Command="{Binding }" WidthRequest="219" FontSize="12">

                                                    </Button>
                                                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1.52" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,-8,0,0">

                                                    </BoxView>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

Comment: use a TableView, or a bindable StackLayout

Comment: @Jason it worked. But, are there any properties for bindable stacklayout for headers like the listview header?

Comment: no, but you can just build your own header

Comment: @Jason yes. I already did. thank you so much

Comment: @error404 Hi, if you have solved that, remember to update the solution in answer when you have time.